# Deleting words with specific beginning in a string

Tags: string, str-replace

```
$string = '@English is a West Germanic @language that was first spoken in early medieval @England and is now a global lingua franca. @It is spoken as a first language by the';
```

How can I remove all the words which starts with a @ in a single action?

What about something linke `str_replace()` ?

```
`$result = 'is a West Germanic that was first spoken in early medieval and is now a global lingua franca. is spoken as a first language by the'`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
echo $string | sed -e 's/@\w*//g'
```

This replaces all substrings matching with the regex @\w* with an empty string. The g flag ensures that multiple strings are being matched.

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated